# getting strings from other classes

Tags: java, android, string, class

hi guys im writing a method that contains a string name from other classes..

i use the String apkName and mcurrentPhotoPath in alot of activites but need to pass the value of them string into my download method.

ive tried this

```
public static class Stringz{
public String APK() {
        return apkNames;
    }

    public String FILEPATH() {
        return mCurrentPhotoPath;
    }
```

}

then in my download method i use

```
Stringz st = new Stringz();
String apkNames = st.APK();
String mCurrentPhotoPath = st.FILEPATH();
```

which works fine for a single activity. but because i have multiple activites using the same string names how can i write it so my method know which string to look for in every activity

thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need one of these two:

1) An instance of `Stringz`

2) A static reference to the Strings you want to access

A static reference you define as:

```
public static String yourString = "Some string";
```

And instance:

```
public Stringz reference = new Stringz();
//and access like:
reference.yourString;
```

Comment: thanks @Lunar will take a look now. i think this actually is my problem ive not set them to static..